# Library not found in Android Studio

Tags: 16.04, android-studio, emulation, adb

I am using Android Studio in Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to run (bundle exec rake run_acceptance_tests) with my emulator in Android Studio (tests), but when I run it I get the following error message:

```
RUNNING EMULATOR emu_19_WXGA720 at : 2017-03-14 12:25:27 +0200
Restarting adb server
Emulator boot
PORT 5554 ready for emulator connection
Checking property dev.bootcomplete
[140310914500416]:ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
Restarting adb server
error: device 'emulator-5554' not found
```

Do I need to install Qt libraries or something else?

Answer (score 5):

I hope this will solve your problem.
I had a freshly installed latest Android Studio and perform all basic steps to run a 'Hello World' project in emulator 
but had a same problem while running emulator from avd manager.
After that i tried running emulator from command line also but faced same problem.
After long debugging i came to find out that it was missing some core library, 
and then solved the problem by selecting checkbox and install emulator from Android Studio Options.
 *Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Android Emulator*

And click Apply and Run project again.
Note :- If already Checked try to reinstall it. 
 
Now its working like a charm.[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: Doesn't  work for me(

Comment: are you able to run emulator from command line ?

Comment: 2 years later and this is exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`ERROR:./android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found` and `Could not launch '../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory` may have been caused by a recent update. A temporary solution (until an update is released to fix the problem) is to launch the emulator using the terminal from within the `/Android/sdk/tools` directory.

Comment: qemu-system-x86 is already the newest version (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.9).But problem is not resolved. And qemu-system-i386 in Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_x64

Comment: sorry, but my mistake, i can t run not emulator, i can t run my rakefile, which has one of function start of emulator.

Comment: On MacOS, default installation, the directory can be found at `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools`.